# How to prevent certain applications/processes from using the VPN on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm currently using a VPN to browse the web, but I have to turn it off when I play games because the latency becomes unbearable (not to mention that if the connection drops, the kill-switch turns on and I disconnect from the game fully).

Is there a way to continue having the VPN take over the entire connection (ie. the safest way to use a VPN), but have a regular internet connection exist, where I route certain traffic through? I know there is ForceBindIP, but games like Overwatch are run from a launcher, so I unless ForceBindIP also applies to processes started by launchers, then it wouldn't work.

The solutions I've seen are either outdated, or require me to manually choose which applications *do* use the VPN, as opposed to the VPN connection being the default route.

I'm using OpenVPN and Windows 10.

EDIT:

I've played around with routes a bit, but it doesn't seem to work. When I run **ipconfig**, my OpenVPN adapter doesn't have a default gateway. But if I run **route print**, there's two entries with 0.0.0.0 for both the Network Destination and Netmask. One of them has the same gateway as my regular WiFi adapter, so my assumption is the second one is the VPN connection (further confirmation is the metric value is lower than my WiFi connection). However, if I add the two IPV4 addresses for whatismyipaddress.com/ to my route table, that site still picks up my VPN IP addresss.

Comment: Are you wanting a [split-tunnel](https://openvpn.net/blog/split-tunneling-for-remote-workforce/), where you have access to resources on the VPN but any traffic not specifically targeting the VPN resources is routed via the internet?

Comment: @Speeddymon: Split tunnel will require using routes and IPs, which the poster wishes to avoid.

Comment: @Speeddymon No, I want it the other way around. I want ALL my traffic to nominally go through the VPN. Then, I want to choose which process bypasses the VPN.

Comment: Consider going the opposite way: If all you want to use the VPN for is web browsing, this can be accomplished with relative ease. IIRC Windows just isn’t equipped to handle it the other way around.

Comment: @DanielB Ideally it should be how I said - all traffic is routed through the VPN nominally, and I specifically prevent certain applications from being routed through the VPN connection. If I just wanted my browser to use my VPN I would've installed a browser VPN.

Comment: "or require me to know the IP address of the servers I don't want to use a VPN for".. how else will the system know what should and shouldn't go over the VPN? The networking stack doesn't have rules for each executable. The only other solution I could think of would be to force game via a application specific proxy but that would be more effort than just specifying the IP ranges.

Comment: In a crude way, I would think such a solution would see that a specific application is connecting to a set of IP addresses, thus data going to those specific destinations would bypass the VPN connection. I've edited my question to include this possible solution (if it's even realistic).

Comment: Either you have a split tunnel or you don't. If you want some traffic to go across the VPN but other traffic not to, regardless of the quantity, or whatever rules you need to apply; then you need a split tunnel. The other option is full tunnel, and as its name implies, all traffic goes through that tunnel. Even adding your own static routes won't get around that. Now, with that context in mind, I can provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With a split-tunnel, you can configure the routes however you like. You can enforce some routes (such as a default route for all traffic) from the server side, and then apply client side static routes that will direct traffic for IPs you know about in advance that you never want to traverse the VPN.

The hard part is solving for issues like when the public IP changes. You're wanting to connect games external to your VPN, so getting the public IPs and configuring routes for those IPs isn't hard, but you'll have to manually update the static routes on each client, and for each game; so it's not exactly elegant - you'll probably want to create some automation around this.

Comment: I've updated my original question since I've tried what you're suggesting but it doesn't seem to work. If I can get this route method working, then my plan was to just listen to what IP addresses a specific process tries to connect to, and then add them to the route table. As far as I understand it, adding routes to the table comes into effect immediately, and unless I make them persistent it will clear after I reconnect.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the route entries you added for whatismyip.com? More than likely, the IPs you added to your routes don't cover each unique host that the website will have your browser send a request out for.

Comment: Open the site in your browser (with or without VPN), right click on the page. Click on Inspect. In the inspect pane, click on the Network tab at the top. Then click back on the webpage, and refresh the page. You will see many connections outgoing for different assets mentioned on the site. You should listen to which IP addresses your web browser is connecting to while browsing to the main page, and add ALL of them, in order to try to fix the issue. Even then, there may be a backend server which you can't directly see which gets your client IP and therefore you have no way to change the route.

Comment: Checking the website is not a good way to verify this.

Comment: So how would I verify it is working?

Comment: If you have a game where you can connect to the server by IP (minecraft could be helpful here) then you could try to add a route for that and connect to it. Watching your netstat output or a wireshark trace would also be helpful, if you're comfortable with those tools already. There are many ways but a lot of the problem, it seems to me, is that you need to make sure you're not dealing with DNS, load balancers, and transparent proxies (all things that you have no control over) when testing your connection.

Comment: Also you could try to add a route for 8.8.8.8 and try to traceroute to that IP on UDP or TCP port 53. That's a public google DNS server, so it should help you to verify the connection is properly routed as well, at least for your testing purposes.

Comment: How do I figure out what gateway to use?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not something I can tell you. It depends on the network, the VPN, and a lot of things really. Networking isn't easy. Start by check the routes without the VPN connected, then compare to the routes with it connected. That will highlight the difference and you can test based on what you find.

Comment: Your questions are going beyond the scope of this post, so I'd ask that you make a new post and accept my answer. You can always change your selection later if someone else provides a better solution.